# Работа со списками в Python, цикл For

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for

Кто нибудь может объяснить на пальцах, почему при таком коде:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 4, 5]

for number in a:
    if number in b:
        a.remove(number)
print(a)
```

В результате получается

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

То есть цикл работает неправильно и не удаляет все двойки из списка, однако если цикл работает уже не по самому списку, а по его копии(срезу), то всё работает правильно:

```
for number in a[:]:
    if number in b:
        a.remove(number)
print(a)

[1, 1, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Два раза в день одни и те же грабли вижу. Надо где-нибудь уже закрепить тему, как делать никогда не надо )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При удалении индексы меняются, и часть элементов не проверяется.

Простой способ решения - обходить `a` с конца.

Comment: Понял про индексы :D Благодарю